# Razor generated HTML Checkbox with Bootstrap 4 always submitting checkbox as false

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I have an issue with the `Html.CheckboxFor()` function on an MVC .NET 5 app.

The Razor code present is here

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i.IsDefault) Make Default
            <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This generates the following HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsDefault field is required." id="IsDefault" name="IsDefault" type="checkbox" value="true" /> Make Default
            <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, when I submit the form, if the box is checked, the posted FORM data from the browser dev tools POSTs

```
IsDefault: false
IsDefault: false
```

And if it is unchecked

```
IsDefault: false
```

I need to capture if the box is checked or not when the form is POSTed.

There is obviously something simple I am doing wrong, and I am sure I have checkboxes working in other parts of the app, and I have even tried copy-pasting, but I still cannot seem to get this working.

Comment: Hi @Matthew Warr, it should be work. Could you please share more details about your view and what is your backend code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `checked` attribute to have the checkbox checked by default:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsDefault field is required." id="IsDefault" name="IsDefault" type="checkbox" value="true" checked /> Make Default
```

And to catch the checked/unchecked status in the action make sure you have a bool parameter in action named `IsDefault` which will catch the value of the check box.